# Certifique-se que o Component está iniciando com a letra maiúscula - React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, google-maps

Estou tentando carregar o Google Maps em um projeto com `React Native` e `TypeScript` porém está me retornando o erro que o *Component* deve ser iniciado com letra maiúscula:

> **Erro**: Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component
> `div` must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start
> component names with a capital letter.

A questão é que o *Component* está com letra maiúscula...

**E está apontado o erro na linha 36:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';



import {
    GoogleMap, 
    Polyline
} from '@react-google-maps/api';

var refMap = React.createRef();

const state = {

    origin: { 
        latitude: -20.6541912, 
        longitude: -45.2418339 
    },
    destination: {
        latitude: -22.6268954, 
        longitude: -44.7512302 },
    originText: '',
    destinationText: '',
    zoom: 13,
    latCenter:-20.525678,
    longCenter:-44.325637

 };

const DetailMaps = () => {

     return(
        <View>
            <GoogleMap
                id="mapaGoogle"
                mapContainerStyle={{
                    height: '100%',
                    width: '100%',
                    position: 'absolute'
                }}
                zoom={state.zoom}
          
                center={{
                    lat: state.latCenter,
                    lng: state.longCenter
                }}
            >
            </GoogleMap>
        </View>
    );
}
```

;

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
Esse problema está ocorrendo, pois você está tentando inserir um component **react** ao invés de um react-native, o que significa que dentro desse component existe conteúdo html que não é permitido dentro de um projeto react-native.
Recomendo que use a biblioteca: [react-native-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-maps)